# SQL Count Distinct Value Oldest DateTime

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm working with two datasets and attempting to create a new column in the output with a count of unique values. In my query I have multiple Case When clauses where a unique string of numbers from one of the tables will dictate a unique string/sentence value in the output. In the Else statement, any of these unique string of numbers that exists in the 2nd table that doesn't exist in the 1st table (last column in 2nd table, 1st column in 1st table) will result in a summed count in the output. My issue is that the count should only be for the oldest DateTime instance of distinct user id's. I built an edge case to check if my output was working correctly, and it was outputting a count for a userid if they had multiple instances of the same identifier but different strings. I want the output to only count once per identifier per distinct user based on the oldest DateTime.

Some data may look like this:

```
1581 | billy | abcd | red dead | company1
1903 | bob   | defg | halo 3   | company2
5849 | lilly | hijk | fortnite | company3
1903 | bob   | hijk | fortnite | company3
```

Some data may look like this:

```
d83j | 2012-09-28 | 2012-09-28 09:00:00.00 | abcd | 1010
np50 | 2012-09-28 | 2012-09-28 10:45:00.00 | abcd | 1581
j99p | 2012-09-28 | 2012-09-28 11:00:00.00 | abcd | 1581
rn2n | 2012-09-28 | 2012-09-28 18:30:00.00 | defg | 1903
rn2n | 2012-09-28 | 2012-09-28 15:30:00.00 | defg | 1903
rn2n | 2012-09-28 | 2012-09-28 07:30:00.00 | defg | 6211
44ko | 2012-09-28 | 2012-09-28 18:30:00.00 | hijk | 5849
```

Here is my query currently:

```
SELECT 
  F.Identifier, F.Videogame, F.Developer,
CASE WHEN S.String='1581' THEN 'Made by billy'
     WHEN S.String='1903' THEN 'Made by bob'
     WHEN S.String='5849' THEN 'Made by lilly'
     ELSE 'worked on by someone else' END AS Final_Name,
     COUNT(distinct S.User_ID) as Count
FROM 
  table1 as F
JOIN 
  table2 as S
ON
  F.Identifier=S.Identifier
GROUP BY
  F.Identifier, F.Videogame, F.Developer, Final_Name
```

I've attempted to include having and where clauses around the count and sub-querying the count S.User_ID, but none of what I'm doing is getting me what I'm looking to achieve.

Actual output right now looks like this:

```
abcd | red dead | company1 | worked on by someone else | 1
abcd | red dead | company1 | Made by billy             | 2
defg | halo 3   | company2 | Made by bob               | 1
defg | halo 3   | company2 | worked on by someone else | 1
hijk | fortnite | company3 | Made by lilly             | 1
```

Because user_id rn2n had multiple instances all with the same identifier, the output should only return the oldest datetime instance (i.e. the 07:30:00.00 instance.) Current output counts distinct user_id per string which is why rn2n counts once for made by bob and once for made by someone else.

Expected output should be this:

```
abcd | red dead | company1 | worked on by someone else | 1
abcd | red dead | company1 | Made by billy             | 2
defg | halo 3   | company2 | worked on by someone else | 1
hijk | fortnite | company3 | Made by lilly             | 1
```

Comment: it is not clear why this line `defg | halo 3   | company2 | Made by bob               | 1` should be eliminated  - please explain the logic using this line

Comment: Since user_id rn2n had 3 instances of the defg identifier, only the oldest datetime (i.e. the 07:30:00) row in table2 should be counted in the output. the abcd identifier in the output can have multiple rows because its coming from different unique user_id's.

Comment: got it. make sense. will answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT F.Identifier, F.Videogame, F.Developer,
CASE WHEN S.String='1581' THEN 'Made by billy'
     WHEN S.String='1903' THEN 'Made by bob'
     WHEN S.String='5849' THEN 'Made by lilly'
     ELSE 'worked on by someone else' END AS Final_Name,
     COUNT(DISTINCT S.User_ID) AS COUNT
FROM `project.dataset.table1` AS F
JOIN (
  SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY datetime LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
  FROM `project.dataset.table2` t
  GROUP BY User_ID

) AS S
ON F.Identifier=S.Identifier
GROUP BY F.Identifier, F.Videogame, F.Developer, Final_Name
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result will be

```
Row Identifier  Videogame   Developer   Final_Name                  Count    
1   abcd        red dead    company1    worked on by someone else   1    
2   abcd        red dead    company1    Made by billy               2    
3   defg        halo 3      company2    worked on by someone else   1    
4   hijk        fortnite    company3    Made by lilly               1
```